# I don't understand groupby behavior in Pandas with categorical data

Tags: pandas, categorical

Case 1 : the groupby is adding 'missing' combinations of 'A' an 'B' ?

Case 2 : the result is the same lengh as the entry dataframe.

If 'A' and 'B' represent integers, I get the same result in both cases.

[image: entry data]

[image: categorical]

[image: integers]

Answer (score 0):

When your keys are `category` dtype, the output contains the product of all combinations even if groups are missing due to `observed=False` default setting of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method.

> **observed**: bool, default False
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

If you use `sample.groupby(['A', 'B'], observed=True)['C'].count().reset_index()`, the output will be the same when `A` and `B` are integers.